# Semantic-UI/ReactJS Dropdown component transition not wroking

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

Using **[Dropdown](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html)** from Semantic-UI *(standalone)*

As you see, in below example, when you toggle on `dropdown`, you see a good transition

```js
$('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" integrity="sha256-9mbkOfVho3ZPXfM7W8sV2SndrGDuh7wuyLjtsWeTI1Q=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js" integrity="sha256-t8GepnyPmw9t+foMh3mKNvcorqNHamSKtKRxxpUEgFI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="ui selection dropdown">
  <input type="hidden" name="gender">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Gender</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to use **[Semantic-UI/ReactJS](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/)** dropdown, as you see in this [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/semantic-ui-react-form-and-dropdown-yrjex), transition not working! is there a way to mix [Transition](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/transition/)  with Dropdown ? or fix transition with `css` or even additional `JS`?

Comment: according to [this issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/2071) it's not implemented yet...

Comment: I believe you can do this but playing `css` transition` after rendered.